# Alphabetical word boundary in PHPs regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, pcre

`\b` specifies a word boundary in regular expressions; however, it treats a digit as a word character. Is there a way of denoting a boundary where digits are not considered part of the word (i.e., just alphabetical characters)?

Must work at the start and end of string like `\b` does.

I'm using PHP's PCRE version of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use custom [assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
 (?<![a-z])word
```

Replaces the leading `\b`.

```
 wordend(?![a-z])
```

Probes that no letter follows your word.
Of course you could also test for more specific character lists, or even just `\s`paces.